# google-api-php-client - Drive - File Insert - Create a text file - Content not being added

Tags: php, file, mime-types, google-api-php-client

I want to create a **plain/text** Mime Type file, using PHP and the Google-API  for Google Drive on Google App Engine.

When I use:

```
'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
```

No content is written to the file.

If I use:

```
'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
'uploadType' => 'media'
```

contents are added to the file.

This code from [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php#step_3_set_up_the_sample):

Shows a line of code for the mimeType of 'text/plain'

```
'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
```

But, again, if I use that, no contents are added to the file.  What are the settings for creating a plain text file and adding content?

My complete code is this:

```
<?php
/* You can NOT see the files created in a Service Account without doing some special stuff.  You need to set some kind
of permissions, and then you can see the files in your SHARED WITH ME section of Google Drive 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302794/google-drive-api-services-account-view-uploaded-files-to-google-drive-using-java*/
session_start();

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');

$client_id = 'your Client ID'; //Client ID
$service_account_name = 'account name'; //Email Address
$key_file_location = 'fileName.p12'; //key.p12

$theDateTime = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
echo "indexService - " . $theDateTime . '<br>';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);

//$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/service/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
//echo '$key: ' . $key. '<br>';

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),
    $key
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

//Begin of code that is same for both service and web

//  If signed in, upload
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  echo 'Got access token <br>';

  $fileData = "This is the file Content: " . $theDateTime;
  $fileName = 'User123_Date';
  echo '$fileName: ' . $fileName . '<br>';
  echo '$fileData: ' . $fileData . '<br>';

  //Upload file with metadata
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($fileName);
  $result2 = $service->files->insert(
      $file,
      array(
        'data' => $fileData,
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
      )
  );

  $theId = $result2->getId();
  $downloadUrl = $result2->getDownloadUrl();
  echo 'the ID: ' . $theId . '<br>';
  echo "Title: " . $result2->getTitle() . '<br>';
  echo "MIME type: " . $result2->getMimeType() . '<br>';
  echo '$downloadUrl: ' . $downloadUrl . '<br>';

  // get the file info as a check
    try {
      echo 'try part <br>';
      $result3 = $service->files->get($theId);
      echo "Title: " . $result3->getTitle() . '<br>';
      //echo "Description: " . $result3->getDescription() . '<br>';
      echo "MIME type: " . $result3->getMimeType() . '<br>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
    };

   if ($downloadUrl) {
     echo 'there is a download url <br>';

    $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      $theContentIs = $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
      echo '$theContentIs: ' . $theContentIs . '<br>';
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      echo 'an error occurred getting file contents <br>';
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    echo 'The file doesnt have any content stored on Drive. <br>';
  }
}

echo "File Upload - Uploading a small file".'<br>';
?>

<?php
echo 'end of code';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a text file with that MimeType, create it from PHP not directly on Drive. That's why that mimetype isn't getting recognized. fopen() can do the trick.